# how to divide all values in a data.frame by one row

Tags: r, dataframe, division

I have a    data.frame like this:

```
df=head(df)       
                                                                                                        t20coreB t20crustB t30crustB t0core t0crust
CellularProcesses 0 1 0 0 0
CellularProcesses2 0 1 0 0 0
CellularProcesses3 0 0 4 4 0
CellularProcesses4 0 0 0 0 0
CellularProcesses5 0 1 0 0 0
CellularProcesses6 12 6 1 12 13

                                                                                                        t10coreA t10crustA t10coreB t10crustB
CellularProcesses 0 0 0 0
CellularProcesses2 0 0 0 0
CellularProcesses3 0 1 15 0
CellularProcesses4 1 0 0 0
CellularProcesses5 1 0 0 0
CellularProcesses6 0 11 5 1

                                                                                                        t30coreA t30crustA t30coreB
CellularProcesses 0 0 0
CellularProcesses2 0 0 0
CellularProcesses3 0 3 1
CellularProcesses4 2 1 0
CellularProcesses5 0 0 1
CellularProcesses6 1 28 5
```

I'd like to divide the values in each column for the value in the last row (in the corresponding column).

I tried:

```
df.normalized=df[1:3,]/df[4,]
```

But it didn't work and I got an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `6.102.266` looks non-numeric. Because of the last row, the columns are all `character` class. May be you need to give more details regarding the last row.

Comment: @akrun, in one word - "French" <sigh>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also divide by keeping it as a `data.frame`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub('[.]', '', x)))
res <- df[1:3,]/unlist(df[4,])[col(df)[-4,]]
```

Or

```
res <- t(t(df[1:3,])/unlist(df[4,]))

res[,1]
#[1] 1.638736e-06 3.277471e-07 7.374310e-06

df[1:3,1]/df[4,1]
#[1] 1.638736e-06 3.277471e-07 7.374310e-06
```

#### Update

The updated data have `numeric` last row `6`

```
 res <- df[1:5,]/unlist(df[6,])[col(df)[-6,]]
 res[,6]
 #[1] NaN NaN NaN Inf Inf
```

You get `NaN`, `Inf` because

```
 df[,6]
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0

 0/0
 #[1] NaN
 1/0
#[1] Inf
```

If you want the `NaN` in any of the columns to be transformed to `0`

```
 res[] <- lapply(res, function(x) replace(x, is.nan(x),0))
```

For both `NaN` and `Inf` to `0`

```
 res[] <- lapply(res, function(x) replace(x, !is.finite(x),0))
```

Another option for `NaN` is

```
 res[res=='NaN'] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(S1 = c("10", "2", "45", "6.102.266"), S2 = c("20", 
"5", "8", "8.392.734"), S3 = c("5", "88", "74", "6.329.533"), 
S4 = c("6", "32", "5", "6.393.165"), S5 = c("18", "85", "61", 
"7.127.333"), S6 = c(12, 45, 23, 810.613), S7 = c("7", "6", 
"2", "5.832.144"), S8 = c("8", "1", "20", "8.560.084"), S9 = c("91", 
"20", "0", "9.133.783"), S10 = c("12", "33", "8", "3.537.480"
), S11 = c("11", "22", "9", "24.708.786"), S12 = c("75", 
"85", "55", "5.928.850")), .Names = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", 
"S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "S11", "S12"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "Reads"))
```

#### New data

```
df <- structure(list(t20coreB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L), t20crustB = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L), t30crustB = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L), t0core = c(0L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 12L), t0crust = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L), t10coreA = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), t10crustA = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 11L), 
t10coreB = c(0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 5L), t10crustB = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), t30coreA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
t30crustA = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 28L), t30coreB = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("t20coreB", "t20crustB", 
"t30crustB", "t0core", "t0crust", "t10coreA", "t10crustA", "t10coreB", 
"t10crustB", "t30coreA", "t30crustA", "t30coreB"), row.names =   c("CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Lysosome[PATH:ko04142];E32125,MANBA,manB;beta-mannosidase[EC:32125]", 
 "CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Lysosome[PATH:ko04142];GBA,srfJ;glucosylceramidase[EC:32145]", 
     "CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Lysosome[PATH:ko04142];HEXA_B;hexosaminidase[EC:32152]", 
 "CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Lysosome[PATH:ko04142];NEU1;sialidase-1[EC:32118]", 
 "CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Lysosome[PATH:ko04142];uidA,GUSB;beta-glucuronidase[EC:32131]", 
  "CellularProcesses;Transportandcatabolism;Peroxisome[PATH:ko04146];ACSL,fadD;long-chainacyl-CoAsynthetase[EC:6213]"
   ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: also in this case are produced NaN and Inf

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis  But, not in the example you showed.  Please provide an example that gives the `NaN`, `Inf`

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis The 6th column is like `dfN[,6]#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0;  0/0
#[1] NaN;
1/0
#[1] Inf`

Comment: Is there a way to transform NaN to 0?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis  What about the `Inf`?  Do you want that to be transformed too?

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you transform your data frame to a numeric matrix:

```
mat <- sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", x)))
mat[1:3, ] / mat[4, ]
```

Comment: It seem to work, but in some cells are produced Inf or NaN... How can I get rid of them?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis Are there some strings that can't be converted to numbers?